# How can i Send response to authorize client?

Tags: wcf

Just finished my first WCF service.

I want to limit the client to get service from my WCF server - so i want to response just to client that have the right password ( password will send as string in one of the argument field ) or just response to client that have specific ip address.

How can i do it in WCF ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "normal" expected behavior would be for the WCF service to:

- return a valid result for those users who are authorized to call that service
- throw a `FaultException` (possibly a typed `FaultException<SecurityNegotiationException>`) for those users who are not authorized

Comment: The password that i need to check on the server - is something that usually done in WCF by just compare strings or there some other way to do it in WCF ?